# Issues with responsive design email template (css and inline styles conflicting)

Tags: css, responsive-design, html-email

I'm having some issues with css and inline styles on an email campaign I'm doing.

Firstly I ended up cheating a bit in that I was hiding elements (display:none;) to make them appear in the right order when using the @media css. The issue here was when displaying on a desktop isp (gmail) it ignored the (display:none;) and ended up showing double content in places. So to the double content disappear I used (display:none !important;) which then affected the mobile version.

There are some mobile templates I've seen online which don't appear to have had much testing as they simply do not work across multiple mail clients.

The code is here if anyone has any suggestions or help http://www.makeyourownmarket.com/test/test-doc.html

Comment: In the style tag, why do you say table[id=header] instead of table#header? That syntax is very uncommon for an id (though not necessarily bad). Out of curiousity, was there a reason for it? :)

Answer (score 5):

Some tips for responsive emails:

- Put your `!important` declaration on all of your `@media only screen and (max-width: 480px)` CSS
- Think of workarounds, if `display:none;` isn't working, try `width:0;height:0;` on your inline CSSand then override with `width:100px !important;height:100px !important;` in your mobile styles
- You will need to do extensive testing, having an account/device for all the significant email clients is the best, but http://www.emailonacid.com works in a pinch.

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend doing a little more research into HTML emails and their limitations.

This article is a good starting point:
http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-to-code-html-emails

Some tips:

- Don't place CSS in a STYLE tag as this won't work across all email clients.
- Use inline CSS only
- Use Tables for layout
- I would be very surprised if media queries would work consistently in email clients. I'd avoid trying to use those and instead concentrate on creating a basic, solid email template which displays consistently across the most popular email clients.

Comment: I grew up as web programmer / designer, and cheap "designer" following "*Use Tables for layout*" was the kind of thing I used to fight all the time. I'm not very active with that regard anymore, but please tell me that the empire is not striking back...

Comment: But isn't that totally different in an email context? I think email clients are using very lightweight html processors, and maybe tables are a simple element to interpret for them.

Comment: Designing HTML emails is way different than designing for modern browsers. Many CSS techniques are unavailable. You may *have* to use tables in order to get the positioning your looking for. It all depends on what mail readers you need to support. It's a huge pain, really.

Answer (score -2):

I dont think responsive design is the right way for emails. Usually emails are made inside the table because of many mail clients. You could find more about this here [Nettuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/getting-started-with-html-emails/)

Comment: Responsive email design is [quite common these days.](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/guides/mobile/)

Comment: It doesnt support gmail, yahoo mail, and outlook. They are the biggest mail service providers, so i think this is not a good solution.

Comment: I totally agree, so that makes us in the minority (or both Gmail users?). The lack of support issue only really arises on a phone though as desktop versions of the clients you mentioned don't need it and fallback to the full width. I think we'd agree that it is not a complete solution, but a common one these days, as most people unfortunately think the world begins and ends with Mac products.

Comment: Both gmail users :) Im looking forward to see responsive mails in full function. But its weird for me that gmail doesnt support it, because google is usually the first one that supports some new features. Its obviously hard to render responsive mail on various devices. Yea I agree on mac products

Comment: It's because web clients don't support style tags in an effort to stop your email busting out of the section of the page it belongs. By keeping all css inline and limiting which css you are allowed to use, there is no way for you to break Gmail or apply global css rules on the page. Media queries don't work inline which is why they are unsupported.

Comment: Ive came across a realy nice article http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/build-responsive-emails